# Maximum number of topics a device can subscribe to in FCM

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Documentation for topic messages for FCM says the following two points

[image]

Just wanted to know what is this excessive number of topics? Any approximate value to it? Also, the documentation doesn't say anything about creation of topics. How to create/delete a topic?

**Another question -**

Document says it takes time to show the topic on firebase console, so, we can't send notifications unless the topic is visible on firebase console (even programmatically)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future questions, please limit yourself to a single question per post. But here are the answers that I know (or a fairly educated guess):

1. The limit on the number of topics a client can subscribe to is to counter abuse. It is not a documented value.
2. A topic is auto-created when a client subscribes to it.
3. There is no API to delete a topic. It will automatically disappears when nobody is subscribed to it anymore.
4. You can only send notifications from the console once the topic shows up. You can send notifications from your app server using the [Firebase Cloud Messaging API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/#how_does_it_work) at any moment.

Comment: Apologies @Frank. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You mentioned "Counter abuse" in The limit on the number of topics a client can subscribe, what do you  mean by this ? what is the maximum number of  topics  a single user can  subscribe???

Comment: Is there any limit on how many unique topics that can be created? ex: Each user will have one unique topic. If number of users increases to millions does it still support?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830098/topics-on-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: Removed the point about not being able to delete a subscription. You can delete a topic by performing an HTTP DELETE using the topic id. See "Delete Push Subscriptions" at: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server

Comment: The maximum number of topics per app instance is 1999. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48334967/753632

Comment: @AndroidDev The documentation you linked is to delete a subscription, not to delete a topic itself. I'm reverting your edit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Actually you can delete a topic indirectly by bulk deleting the subscriptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37650817/753632

Comment: I added a note to clarify that.