# How many topics an app instance can subscribe in FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

As mentioned in FCM documents, unlimited topic can be created for one Firebase application. But as the [Firebase Admin SDK document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors): explains an error:

> **messaging/too-many-topics**:- A registration token has been subscribed to the maximum number of topics and cannot be subscribed to any more.

I was not able to find this threshold value of maximum number of topics. Can anybody explain, what is the limit? **How many topics an app instance can subscribe to in FCM?**

Comment: I could not find at firebase document. But I have seen another question on this platform asks 'why only 3 topics'.

Comment: @HakanC That sounds more like the number of topics you can use in a single subscription. It was also recently increased from 3 to 5. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I couldn't find any document stating that in one call one registration token can be subscribed to multiple topic. Could you point to that documentation where it is mentioned about subscribing to 5 topics at a time?

Comment: Never mind, I got it the wrong way around: you can **send** messages to multiple topics at once, by writing expressions as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#build_send_requests. That also contains the limit I was thinking of "You can include up to five topics in your conditional expression..."

Comment: AFAIK, limitations regarding topics were all removed (topic creation and subscriptions) after moving from C2DM to GCM (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15017586/4625829)) -- looking at this [old blogpost](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/google-cloud-messaging-weve-come-long.html?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=1cb848077c-Android_Weekly_184&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-1cb848077c-337844217) again, it does only say that creating topics are unlimited, so are the number of subscribers, but not the subscription for token. Will take a look around again.

Comment: @AL. Thanks for formatting my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer by running a subscription script for an app instance. After subscribing to 1999 topics, for the next subscription it started giving error: **messaging/too-many-topics**.

So **the threshold value is 1999**.

Comment: is there any paid plan if we want to have more than that?

Answer (score 8):

As much as the selected answer is correct, I'll like to post an absolute answer here.
[Google Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#top_of_page)

> **Some things to keep in mind about topics:**

- > Topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each topic.
  >   However, FCM enforces limits in these areas:
- > One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.
- > If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app instances.
- > The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.