# Is it possible to create Firebase Cloud Messaging topics without a device token?(web-app)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

The point of this is to create 100 topics from a list. When this is done my application will go through this list once every day to check for upcoming events. A message will be sent to the subscribed users if the app finds an event on a particular topic. I will also try to implement some logic to check if there are users subscribed to this particular topic.

Comment: There is no explicit API to create a topic. Topics are automatically created when a user subscribes to them or when you send a message to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts to your question:

Firebase topic subscription is officially documented only for devices. In other words, only devices with device tokens can subscribe to a topic.  Look at AWS SNS topics for topics on which other applications can subscribe.

Secondly, for your use case, topics may not be the solution.  Generally, a topic is not like a queue from which you can retrieve a message.  Generally, a topic will only send messages to subscribers already actively subscribed to the topic.  If there is no subscriber on the topic when a message is received, the message disappears.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will take a look at how I can solve this with AWS SNS API.

Comment: AWS SNS allows lambda functions, among other types of subscribers, to subscribe to a topic.  You can then do whatever you want with the message contained within the SNSEvent passed to the lambda function.  For example, you can write it to a DB.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't think this is possible. The way I understand how Topics work is that (from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37650817/4625829), also mentioned it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382345/4625829)):

> a topic is created when there is at least 1 subscriber and it also gets automatically deleted when there are no more subscribers.

Regardless if it's for web-app or mobile app, having a registration token is necessary for Topic Messaging.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of the fcm topics and was hoping for a simple solution to this problem, but thank you for the response.