Rust google-fcm1 create topic subscriptions in Rust
I'm currently using the google-fcm1 crate in Rust to send Firebase messages but looking for a away to also receive messages for certain topics.
The documentation says nothing about subscribing to topics, but from my experience this isn't documentation to brag about.

I think this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607575/is-it-possible-to-create-firebase-cloud-messaging-topics-without-a-device-token
